# Counter Strike Source Anti-Cheat

Tags: counter-strike-source

I'm trying to start a Counter Strike: Source Tournament on the Internet. But a really important problem is all the cheating done in the game. There are several powerful anti-cheats for Counter Strike 1.6 like `sXe Injected`, but I need one for CS:S.

**Is There a Powerful Anti-Cheat for Counter Strike: Source?**

Answer (score 2):

There are many 3rd-party anti-cheats for CS:S, however most of them are maintained by a tournament organisation like ESL's Wire, ESEA's client, CEVO has CMN3, etc...

The most efficient AntiCheat not directly linked to a competitive organisation is EasyAntiCheat. It requires a plugin to be installed on the server and is sadly not free.

http://www.easyanticheat.net/index

I also found UCP Anti-Cheat, http://ucp-anticheat.org.
I hadn't heard of it and it doesn't seem very popular, which means that there aren't many private cheats supporting it. It's free.